# Output an equation in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a simple calculator, but I also have to display the equation and answer on tkinter. The only thing I could do is get the answer to show in tkinter, not the equation and answer. Like `a + b = c`.

```
from tkinter import *
import time 

master = Tk()

canvas_width = 400
canvas_height = 400

w = Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, bg="#B7F9E3")
w.pack()

a = int(input("enter first operand: "))
operation = input("enter operator: ")
b = int(input("enter second operand: "))
d = 

def add(a,b):
    c = a + b
    print(c)

def subtract(a, b):
    c = a - b
    print(c)

def division(a, b):
    c = a / b
    print(c)

def multiply(a, b):
    c = a * b
    print(c)

if operation == "+" or operation == "+":
    add(a, b)

if operation == "-" or operation == "-":
    subtract(a, b)

if operation == "/" or operation == "/":
    division(a, b)

if operation == "*" or operation == "*":
    multiply(a, b)

if operation == "+":
    w.create_text(100, 50, font=("times new roman", 16), text="Addition Results")
    w.create_text(200, 200, font=("times new roman", 16), text=d)

if operation == "-":
    w.create_text(100, 50, font=("times new roman", 16), text="Subtraction Results")
    w.create_text(200, 200, font=("times new roman", 16), text=d)

if operation == "*":
    w.create_text(100, 50, font=("times new roman", 16), text="Multiplication Results")
    w.create_text(200, 200, font=("times new roman", 16), text=d)

if operation == "/":
    w.create_text(100, 50, font=("times new roman", 16), text="Division Results")
    w.create_text(200, 200, font=("times new roman", 16), text=d)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign to the variable `d`.

Try changing your function definitions to be like this:

```
def add(a,b):
    c = a + b
    return str(c)
```

and the `if` statements to be like this:

```
if operation == "+":
    d = add(a,b)
```

You could make the equation like this:

```
x = 1
y = 2
operation = "+"
equation = str(x) + operation + str(y)
print(equation)
# 1+2
```

Comment: but how would i get like the equation to show in tkinter?